# Unbiased estimator of regression coefficient in high dimension

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, unbiased-estimator, high-dimensional

Is there any unbiased estimator for the regression coefficient $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^p$, p >> 1, where
$$
y_k = x_k^T\beta + \epsilon \in \mathbb{R}?
$$
Note that $x_k \in \mathbb{R}^p$ and $\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2)$, for some $\sigma > 0$.

Comment: It would be more standard to use $p$ instead of $n$ for the dimension and then use $n$ to denote sample size; consider updating your post. With this new notation, how large is $p$ relative to $n$? If $p<n$, you can use OLS.

Comment: It is written as it is. In your notation, p = n, n = 1.

Comment: Would the [tag:gauss-markov-theorem] not apply?

Comment: How large is $n$? Is it larger or smaller than $p$? If $p<n$, you can use OLS.

Comment: Please read the question description as it is. I have specified that p >> n = 1. I am less confident on the existence of unbiased estimator in this setting.

Comment: @Dave OLS solution doesn't even make sense in p >> n setting since the matrix inversion may not even be defined.

Comment: @user808843 Are you sure you want to set $n=1?$

Comment: @Dave Yes, that's my intention. But I would also like to see if the unbiased estimator exists in p >> n >> 1 setting, since OLS doesn't seem to be valid.